# newwrite: Adding text to a existing outfile

Tags: output, write

[image]

I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\newwrite\myoutfile
\immediate\openout\myoutfile=\jobname-myoutfile.txt
\immediate\write\myoutfile{
aaa
}
\immediate\closeout\myoutfile

\section{Test: Input the Result}
\input{\jobname-myoutfile.txt}
\end{document}
```

which gives me the external file `jobname-myoutfile.txt` with

```
aaa
```

inside.

*How can I add new text, like `bbb` (in a newline!), to the outfile?*

So that I will have

```
aaa
bbb
```

Comment: why are you closing the file if you want to append more?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I do not know all the "newwrite"-commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah Ok, I think I understand

Comment: @cis As soon as you close a file you cannot append to it (with just TeX facilities); you can't input it unless you first close it.

Answer (score 2):

It should work like

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\newwrite\myoutfile
\immediate\openout\myoutfile=\jobname-myoutfile.txt
\immediate\write\myoutfile{
aaa
}

\immediate\write\myoutfile{
bbb
}

\immediate\closeout\myoutfile


\section{Test: Input the Result}
\input{\jobname-myoutfile.txt}
\end{document}
```